# Can't connect to docker from WSL

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have checked the option `Expose the daemon on tcp...` in docker on windows, and am now trying to connect from WSL. I have run all those commands:

```
# Update the apt package list.
sudo apt-get update -y

# Install Docker's package dependencies.
sudo apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common

# Download and add Docker's official public PGP key.
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

# Verify the fingerprint.
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

# Add the `stable` channel's Docker upstream repository.
#
# If you want to live on the edge, you can change "stable" below to "test" or
# "nightly". I highly recommend sticking with stable!
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"

# Update the apt package list (for the new apt repo).
sudo apt-get update -y

# Install the latest version of Docker CE.
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce

# Allow your user to access the Docker CLI without needing root access.
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

echo "export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

However, `docker info` only gives me:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

What might be wrong? I have been trying this all day. I am running WSL and Ubuntu 18.04, not WSL 2, as the update that brings WSL 2 doesn't seem to be avaible yet without an insider build.

Comment: did you expose the port on your windows host? you need to expose it manually.

Answer (score 0):

if you run `env | sort` do you see the `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375` variable? if not you may need to run `source ~/.bashrc` to load the new environment variable into the current console.

Alternatively start a new terminal instance.

Also and this may seem like a daft question but i have to ask, is docker running correctly? from powershell if you run `docker info` does it return the status of the docker server?